# shell >& operator?

Tags: bash

I have a question about what I think is an operator or argument passer but google hasn't turned up anything. The script this is contained in is

```
#!/bin/sh
ln mopac.in FOR005
mopac >& FOR006
mv FOR006 mopac.out
```

When I call "mopac mopac.in", the program runs fine, but, for my needs, mopac is called within another program by using this script, but it seems like the input file is failing to pass so mopac is not running. I don't understand what the ">&" is supposed to do so I am having problems troubleshooting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>& FILE` is deprecated `bash` (from `csh`) shorthand for `> FILE 2>&1`, that is, redirect both standard output and standard error.  (If `/bin/sh` is not `bash`, as is true on a number of Linux distributions, this will elicit an error.)  Older `bash` (before 3.0) preferred this form, so most newer `bash` still understand it, although possibly very recent `bash` has finally removed it as they seem to finally be removing deprecated constructs of late.

Your script there is not passing `mopac.in` at all, but appears to be assuming that `mopac` will read its input from `FOR005`, so uses `ln` to make it available there.  Perhaps you should change the script to read `mopac.in` as a parameter, just as you're running it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation here : http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

```
>&j
  # Redirects, by default, file descriptor 1 (stdout) to j.
  # All stdout gets sent to file pointed to by j.
```